# The method getX() in the type Node is not applicable for the arguments (Location, int)

Tags: java

I am trying to call two methods getY(origin, scale) and getX(origin, scale) and while the compiler is fine with getY(origin, scale) it kicks up a fuss and gives the above complaint when I try to call getX(origin, scale). Working in Eclipse.

```
boolean topQuads = (node.getY(origin, scale) < yMidPoint);
boolean bottomQuads = (node.getY(origin, scale) > yMidPoint);


if (node.getX(origin, scale) < xMidPoint) {
    if (topQuads) { 
        index = 1;
    } else if (bottomQuads) { 
        index = 2;
    }
} else if (node.getX(origin, scale) > xMidPoint) { 
    if (topQuads) {
        index = 0;
    } else if (bottomQuads) { 
        index = 3;
    }
}
```

Here is where I defined my methods:

```
public int getX(Location origin, int scale) {
    return loc.asPoint(origin, scale).x;
}

public int getY(Location origin, int scale) {
    return loc.asPoint(origin, scale).y;
}
```

In fact if I try to define any method that does this not named getY the complainer will not compile.

Comment: Are the `origin` and `scale` variables referenced in the first code snippet actually set to valid `Location` and `int` types? That portion of the code is not included.

Comment: For that matter, are both of these snippets from the same Java class `Node` or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes origin and scale are both parameters from the method and no the first snippet is from another class I am working on. The weird part is how getY(Location, int) works while getX(Location, int) doesn't even though they are practically the same method.

Comment: Have you tried to find out whether this is a compiler issue or an IDE issue? Meaning, if you put this in a file, and compile it in the terminal with javac, does it work? It kindof sounds like the IDE is confused because the code looks OK to me. If so, you might also try to fix it by cleaning and rebuilding your entire workspace (somewhere in the eclipse menus ...)

Comment: another reason i just came up with, do you extend a class or interface that already defines a getX method? maybe with different parameters and/or return types?

Comment: You should show more code, i.e. in which class you implemented your methods. The problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for all the quick comments, you guys are rad. It must have been a problem with the compiler/IDE. Cleaning it didn't work but copy pasting the code into a new instance of the class fixed the problem.